# django social auth parse backend name and uid in template

Tags: python-social-auth, django-socialauth

I need to render between a

the backend name and uid used by a logged in user.

Just as I do

Hello {{ user.username }}  !

I need to do

Backend name: {{ dont know }}

I need to do

Uid: {{ dont know }}

I am not sure which value I am able to query in the template.
Thnaks.

EDIT:
SOLVED:

{{user.social_auth.get.provider}}
{{ user.social_auth.get.uid }}

Thats the way.
Thanks!

Comment: Look into https://github.com/python-social-auth/social-app-django/blob/master/social_django/context_processors.py#L29 that will give you backends and also the ones associated with the current user.

Comment: Should I do something like: <p> Backend name: {{ backends.name }} </p>

Sorry I don't understand how can I know which data I have available in the template, I mean which objects such as 'user'

Comment: There's some docs here http://python-social-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration/django.html#template-context-processors, you can also drop the value in the template and inspect from there or do it from a Python shell

Comment: Sorry mate, I cant make it work.
I have tryed {{backends.associated.provider }} but no luck

Comment: `backends.associated` is a `list`. You need to pick an item from it.